# watir-webdriver ignore error how to

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using ruby+watir-webdriver to download daily files from a website.  Some days there is no data available to download.  If data is available a download link is visible on the page and no download link if there is no data.  How can I make the script not error and stop if the link is not found? I want the script to continue on ignoring the error.

Looking to do something like "if then else"

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the link exists using:

```
browser.link(:id, 'your_link_id').exists?
```

If the link exists you can click it (and otherwise skip clicking it):

```
if browser.link(:id, 'your_link_id').exists?
  browser.link(:id, 'your_link_id').click
else
  #Do nothing. Note that you do not actually need this else statement.
end
```

Comment: Even shorter: `browser.link(:id, 'your_link_id').click if browser.link(:id, 'your_link_id').exists?`